# Why isn't this Python import working?

Tags: python, class, module, import

I have three modules:

plugin_grt.py

fragments.py

helpers.py

Right at the top of plugin_grt.py I have

```
from jpa_export_helpers import SourceFile, Mysql, Conv, Columns, Column, Table, ForeignKey, Index, Catalog, Inheritance
```

which works, that is I can use Table.whateverMethod(...) without problems. Now when I add the same import to the top of the fragments.py module I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Kawu\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\modules\jpa_export_plugin_grt.py", line 53, in <module>
    from jpa_export_helpers import SourceFile, Mysql, Conv, Columns, Column, Table, ForeignKey, Index, Catalog, Inheritance

  File "C:\Users\Kawu\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\modules\jpa_export_helpers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from jpa_export_fragments import Type, EnumValue

  File "C:\Users\Kawu\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\modules\jpa_export_fragments.py", line 2, in <module>
    from jpa_export_helpers import SourceFile, Mysql, Conv, Columns, Column, Table, ForeignKey, Index, Catalog, Inheritance

ImportError: cannot import name SourceFile
```

Why isn't this working? The only workaround is to import the classes right where they're needed, but it's not something I like (at least for now):

```
def getPrimaryKeyColumns(self):
    from jpa_export_helpers import Columns
    return Columns.getPrimaryKeyColumns(self.table.columns)
```

Note, I'm originally a Java guy so importing "at will" seems strange to me. Anyway, what's the problem here?

Comment: Are `jpa_export_fragments` and `jpa_export_helpers` yours? They're causing the error after all. `plugin_grt` is not the problem.

Comment: Noting what of plugins_grt and fragments import what, in what order would make the question (and problem) more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note how there is no error in the stacktrace related to anything other than importing. I found that sort of error almost always is related to <strike>recursive</strike> circular imports.

Answer (score 2):

When you import into a module, you import into the module's namespace. Thus when you have

```
 from jpa_export_helpers import SourceFile
```

in `plugin_jrt_py` you have actually created a name `plugin_jrt_py.SourceFile`. Following namespace resolution, within `plug_in_jrt.py` that name can be shortened to `SourceFile` but only within `plug_in_jrt`.

Because an import has side effects, the `import` statement is careful not to import a module twice.

You don't specify a calling sequence, but I suspect that `fragments.py` is imported by `plugin_jrt.py` and so the name is not accessible without qualification.

Try dropping the `from` clauses and the error will become more apparent.